# Sums of squares are closed under division

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory

Surprisingly, we got only one question for our 2-hour exam and I think nobody solved it. Here is the problem:

> Assuming that $K$ is a field, show that $S$ is stable under addition,  multiplication and division, where $S$ is defined as follow:
>   $$S=\left\{\sum_{i=1}^{n}{x_i}^2 \mid n\in \Bbb N ,\ x_i\in K\right\}.$$

Comment: I guess this is the intended set?

Comment: Additian and multiplication are trivial. As $0\in S$, what does it mean for $S$ to be stable under division?

Comment: just to correct addition and multiplication are not trivial

Comment: @Servaes it is likely meant that if $x,y\in S$ and $y\neq0$ then $xy^{-1}\in S$. Since $S$ is stable under multiplication and $1\in S$ this is equivalent to $y^{-1}\in S$ whenever $y\in S, y\neq0$.

Comment: Addition: Trivial.  Any sum of two finite sums of squares is a finite sum of squares.  

Multiplication: Trivial.  Any product of two squares is a square and the distributive property shows that a product of two finite sums has finitely many terms.

Comment: Btw to whoever downvoted: Please leave a comment about why you feel it is justified.

Comment: I downvoted because the question and subsequent comment show no effort whatsoever.

Comment: @Servaes my efforts are irrelevants , I still think about the problem .. when I got something I will post it don't worry

Comment: I disagree. See also [this meta post](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/8998/closing-questions-that-show-no-effort-official-policy) and its top voted answer, and the answers' top voted comment. But feel free to disagree, it's just a downvote.

Comment: @Seginus: You did not even take care to properly punctuate and capitalize the question. That's just disrespectful.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Addition: Trivial.  Any sum of two finite sums of squares is a finite sum of squares.

Multiplication: Trivial.  Any product of two squares is a square and the distributive property shows that a product of two finite sums has finitely many terms.

Division: Suppose that $a=\sum_{i=1}^n x_i^2$ is not zero.  We would like to show that $a^{-1}\in S$ (using s.harp's comment).  If $n=1$, then the inverse of $a$ is trivial.  The first interesting case is when $n=2$  Suppose that $a=x_1^2+x_2^2$.

Now, 
$$
\frac{1}{x_1^2+x_2^2}=\frac{x_1^2+x_2^2}{(x_1^2+x_2^2)^2}=\left(\frac{x_1}{x_1^2+x_2^2}\right)^2+\left(\frac{x_2}{x_1^2+x_2^2}\right)^2
$$
The denominators are OK because this is a field.  All higher $n$'s are generalizations of this case.

Comment: Very nice observation!

Comment: We posted at the same time. +1

Comment: how can we generalise this ?

Comment: @Seginus The obvious generalization where you replace the square by any other power should also work.  For other generalizations, perhaps it would be good to open a new question so that it gets more attention.

Comment: @Segmus In fact it generalizes further than powers, e.g. see the remark in my answer.

Answer (score 14):

$$\frac{1}{x_1^2+x_2^2+x_3^2}=\frac{x_1^2}{(x_1^2+x_2^2+x_3^2)^2}+\frac{x_2^2}{(x_1^2+x_2^2+x_3^2)^2}+\frac{x_3^2}{(x_1^2+x_2^2+x_3^2)^2}$$

Comment: Posting at the same time +1

Answer (score 14):

$\begin{align}{\bf Hint} \ \ a\neq 0\
\Rightarrow&\ \ \color{#c00}{a^{\large -2}} =\, (a^{\large -1})^{\large 2} \in S\ \ \text{by $\,S\,$ contains all squares}\\
{\rm so}\ \ \ a\in S\ \Rightarrow&\ \ a^{\large -1} =\, a\cdot \color{#c00}{a^{\large-2}}\in S\ \ \text{by $\,S\,$ is closed under multipication}
\end{align}$

**Remark** $ $ You asked how it generalizes. The above idea works not only for squares, but for any positive power, i.e. we can obtain $\,a^{-1}\,$ from any of its positive powers via $\,a^{\large -1} = a^{\large n-1}(a^{\large -1})^{\large n}.$ Also the only property of squares (or powers) employed in proving multiplicative closure is that they are closed under multiplication. These observations lead to the following generalization.

**Theorem** $ $ Suppose $K$ is a field, $M$ is a subset of $K$ and $S$ is the set of all sums of elements of $M.$

$(1)\ \ S$ is closed under multiplication if $M$ is closed under multiplication.

$(2)\  \ S$ is closed under division (by all nonzero elements) if $S$ is both closed under multiplication, and every $\,a\in K$ has some positive power $\,a^{\large n}\in S.$

**Proof** $\ (1)\,$ is an immediate consequence of the distributive law. $\ (2)\ $ follows as above, namely if $\,0\neq s\in S\,$ then by hypothesis $\,(s^{\large -1})^{\large n}\in S\,$ for some $\,n\geq 1\,$ thus $\,s^{\large n-1}(s^{\large -1})^{\large n} = s^{\large -1}\in S\,$ because $S$ is closed under multiplication. Hence $\,a\in S\,\Rightarrow\,as^{-1} = a/s\in S,\,$ so $S$ is closed under division.

Comment: I found this question 9 hours late (from the Hot List). but I'll add this answer anyhow since I think it clarifies closure under inverses, hence closure under division (the only tricky part).